Python typing : subclass dependant return typing
I have a function which takes as an argument a class (in the example, any subclass of Base), and return the result of calling fn() as a static method on said class.
Given that different subclasses may return different types (in the example int or str), I'm trying to find a way to type all this so that the IDE knows which type to expect when calling the fn_caller() function depending on the class passed as a parameter.
I have tried TypeVar, but so far I can't find in the documentation a way to specify that the return type of fn_caller should match the return type of a specific function of the class it receives as a parameter.

class Base:

    @classmethod
    def fn(cls) -> ???:
        return None


class A(Base):

    @classmethod
    def fn(cls) -> int:
        return 0


class B(Base):

    @classmethod
    def fn(cls) -> str:
        return "str"



def fn_caller(c: Base) -> ???:
    return c.fn()

a = fn_caller(A) # a should be explicitly int

b = fn_caller(B) # b should be explicitly str

Any help would be appreciated !

Technically you're breaking LSP unless you actually meant for a generic container / operator class

What do you mean by "breaking LSP" ?

Liskov substitution principle.  If you use generics it means that your base is completely unique per content type. Which might be true, but depends further upon the use-case.

So, after trying a bunch of things, turns out I only need to use a TypeVar in the fn_caller() definition
ContentType = TypeVar("ContentType")

class Base(Generic[ContentType]):

    @classmethod
    def fn(cls) -> ContentType:
        return None


class A(Base[int]):

    @classmethod
    def fn(cls) -> int:
        return 0


class B(Base[str]):

    @classmethod
    def fn(cls) -> str:
        return "str"


ReturnType = TypeVar("ReturnType")

def fn_caller(c: Base[ReturnType]) -> ReturnType :
    return c.fn()



You can reuse the same typevar without declaring separate ReturnType.
